# Dealing with dependencies

Tags: design-patterns, dependencies

Is it considered a good practice to pass needed dependencies to method that requires them instead of passing those all dependencies to object constructor? Lets say I have a object that needs to be drawn. Is it considered a good idea to pass renderer to that object's draw() method or I should pass renderer to that object's constructor in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one rule you can use - **if the class instance is useless without the dependencies,** i.e. the dependencies are "must have" / mandatory, **they should be passed to constructor**.

The idea is that the object should be fully (as possible) initialized after the constructor is called. After all that's what constructors are for, initialization.

Consequently should be optional dependencies set using setters.

Answer (score 0):

What you are pointing to is called [flyweight pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) and I believe it should be used when your application need to create high number of objects of almost similar nature.

There are two terms basically used: `Intrinsic State` and `Extrinsic state`.

**Intrinsic State** Intrinsic state is the one which is can be shared among class member.

**Extrinsic state**- The extrinsic state is one which varies and cannot be shared among class members.

pattern of capturing the extrinsic parameter as the method parameter instead of making it instance member is called `Flyweight pattern`.

For more detail on flyweight you can visit this articles [here](http://javapapers.com/design-patterns/flyweight-design-pattern/)

When to consider using Flyweight pattern.

**1.** Need to create large number of objects and its memory cost needs to be reduced.

**2**. There is extrinsic state members in your class design

Answer (score 0):

It would be better invert dependencies between object that needs to be drawn and renderer object, at that renderer object may include method `Draw` with parameter representing a object that needs to be drawn.

If we abstract from the example, it quite legally to provide operation-specific parameters in the method.